# android convert byte[] containing netagive numbers to string and send it with post

Tags: java, android

I been busting my head on this,
I'm using BlowFish to encrypt my data, this data (byte[]) is sent to the server and I need to save the data on the device, so i want to save it on my DB as String.

The problem stared when I wanted to convert the byte[] to String because it containing negative numbers.
I tried many char sets but no good, java byte are unsigned....

any suggestions?

Comment: _java byte are unsigned_ AFAIK, no, they are signed.

Comment: Describe "saving as a string". If it's coming in as a byte array, can't you use a blob?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the negative numbers that are the problem - it's the fact that you're trying to convert the result of encryption - essentially arbitrary binary data - into a string directly.

You should use hex or base64 to encode this instead. As you're on Android, you can use the `Base64` class:

```
byte[] encryptedData = ...;
String base64 = Base64.encode(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Then when you're decrypting:

```
String base64 = loadFromDatabase(); // Or whatever
byte[] encryptedData = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DeFAULT);
```

That's assuming you even need it as a `String` in the first place. You should consider storing the encrypted data as a blob instead.

Comment: thank u! its working, but another thing, originally the data(byte[]) was written to file and then sent via Post, if I dont want to use the file anymore and i want to use String with my data and send the data on the string, how to send it without changing anything on the server because the String base 64 is different then the byte[] file....

Comment: @joseRo: It's not at all clear what you mean by "send the data on the string". But if the file was written from the original byte array, then you should be able to load the file *back* as a byte array.